# ibus-typing-booster doesnt show up in input sources

Tags: keyboard, language-support, ibus

I have installed Ibus-typing-booster for the first time and have tried logging out and rebooting I followed the stops as in the docs while adding new input source i could not find "Other (Typing Booster)". I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that didn't work either.
I also made sure that my keyboard input method system is IBUS.

Ubuntu version: 21.04 with GNOME Desktop

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following in the terminal and then tried again and worked:

```
ibus restart
```